# how to check if a parameter exists in params?

Tags: grails, groovy

```
for ( boldParam in [para1, para2, para2, para4, para5] ) {
    if(/* boldParam exists in params */)
        ilike(boldParam,'%' + params.boldParam + '%')
    }
}
```

I would like to write something like above. I'm trying to avoid the following multiple if statements:

```
if (params.para1)
     ilike('para1','%' + params.para1+ '%')
if (params.para2)
     ilike('para2','%' +params.para2+ '%')
if (params.para3)
     ilike('para3','%' + params.para3+ '%')
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`params` is a `Map`, so you can use `containsKey()`:

```
for (boldParam in [para1, para2, para2, para4, para5]) {
   if (params.containsKey(boldParam)) {
      ilike(boldParam, '%' + params.boldParam + '%')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Trying to retrieve property that does not exist will give you `null`. That means you can simply do

```
if (!params.missing) {
   println("missing parameter is not present within request.")
}
```

In different use case you could also give a try to safe dereference operator `?.`.  For example:

```
params.email?.encodeAsHTML()
```

Comment: Nice and simple does it every time.

Comment: Works for confirming that param is there, too:
`if (!!params.non-missing) {
   println("non-missing parameter is present within request.")
}`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative used by me:

```
['param1','param2','param3','param4','param5'] /* and it also could come from a service */
.each {
    if (params["${it}"]) filters["${it}"] = params["${it}"] 
} /* Do it in your controller and then send $filters to your service */
```